# How to remove click handler for actionccell?

Tags: gwt

I want to remove click handler for action cell based upon some input from object. How can this be done?

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
public static Column<vTO, vTO> 
createReissueButtonColumn(String columnName) {
   ActionCell<VolunteerTO> reListCell = new ActionCell<VTO>("Reissue", 
      new ActionCell.Delegate<VTO>() { 
         @Override 
         public void execute(VTO object) { 
            // code to be executed 
         }
      }) 
      { 
         @Override 
         public void render(Cell.Context context,VTO value,SafeHtmlBuilder sb) { 
            if(null != value.getStatus() && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(value.getStatus())) {
               super.render(context,value,sb); 
            } 
         }
   };

   Column<VTO, VTO> reListColumn = new Column<VTO, VTO>(reListCell) { 
      @Override 
      public VTO getValue(VTO object) {
         return object; 
      } 
   }; 

   reListColumn.setDataStoreName(columnName);
   reListColumn.setSortable(false);
   return reListColumn;
}
```

Comment: I added the code from your suggested edit on Andrei's answer to the question. Just so you know, the question is where you should be including updated information like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply ignore the click (do nothing) based on your conditions.

EDIT:
In your code, in the execute() method you can either do something, or don't do it - based on a particular condition.

Alternatively, you can cancel a click event on this column:

```
unitTable.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<Unit>() {
    @Override
    public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<Unit> event) {
        if ("click".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
            if (event.getColumn() != myTable.getColumnIndex(reListColumn)) {
                // Check some condition. If necessary:
                event.setCanceled(true);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: give ur mail id. i will share u?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I've added it for him. He was just a bit confused as to where to put it.